# The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I'm all new, and I'm trying to create a blog using Ruby on rails on windows 8.1.

I've made most of it, but it gives me "The action 'show' could not be found for CommentsController".

I've read several places it might be a lack of a javascript, but I have no idea where to post it.

```
<h1><%= @post.title %> </h1>

<%= @post.text %>

<h2>Comments</h2>

<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<p><%= comment.text %></p>
<p><%= time_ago_in_words comment.created_at %></p>
<p><%= link_to "Delete comment", [@post, comment], :method  => :delete,         :confirm => "Are you sure?" %></p> 
<% end %> 

<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
<p><%= f.text_area :text, :size => '40x10' %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "Post comment" %></p>
<% end %>

<p>
<%= link_to "Tilbage", posts_path %>
|
<%= link_to "Rediger", edit_post_path(@post) %>
|
<%= link_to "Slet", @post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Er du sikker?" %>
</p>
```

This is my code in question. Any help is appreciated :)
Edit: If there is other parts you need, just let me know

Edit:
CommentController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
params.permit!
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
@comment.save

redirect_to @post
end

def destroy
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
@comment.destroy

redirect_to @comment.post
end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get 'comments/create'

get 'comments/destroy'

resources :posts do
resources :comments
end
```

Comment: Do you have a class called CommentsController with a method called `show` in it?

Comment: Paste your routes and comments_controller

Comment: edited with new info

Comment: when you get this error?

Comment: on new comment submit or destroy comment?

Comment: When i try to destroy

Comment: I'm wondering if your associations between posts and comments is the issue. Can you show the comments.rb Model?

Comment: Looks like this `class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
    end`